# memtest not found in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99

I'm trying to clear an array and thought I would use `memtest()`.

I used it like this: `memtest(ptr->arr, 0, sizeof ptr->arr)`. ptr is a pointer to a struct and arr holds 100 elements.

I get this error, however:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'memtest' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Do I need to import some library? I've imported stdio.h, stdlib.h, and ctype.h.

Comment: did you mean to use `memset` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no such thing as `memtest()` in standard C. You probably meant [`memset()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

If, after fixing that minor typo, you still have such *implicit declaration* issues, check if you're including [<string.h>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/), as that's were `memset()` and friends live in.

Comment: Thanks! I did get the implicit issue again. `<string.h>` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have confused the [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) function for a non-existent function called `memtest`

The compiler is complaining that there are no headers which define the `memtest` function and so it is assumed to be implicitly defined by being implemented in the same compilation module without a forward definition.

[This Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjazh/index.html) is some short documentation on the warning and change in C99.

To get rid of such warnings, even for existant functions, the correct header needs to be included in the C file where you use the function. In the case of `memset` that is the `<string.h>` header.

Comment: Thanks, I did mess it up.